# Finding /dev Mount Point for Sensor

Tags: sensor, mount

I am trying to connect to an [Airmar 200WX](http://www.airmartechnology.com/2009/products/marine-product.asp?prodid=200) and not having much luck finding the `/dev` mount point of the sensor.

I have the sensor plugged in on boot and `dmesg` displays the following:

```
[    1.150836] udevd[99]: starting version 175
[    1.157625] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using musb-hdrc
[    1.276745] usb 1-1: ep0 maxpacket = 8
[    1.277966] usb 1-1: default language 0x0409
[    1.284552] usb 1-1: udev 2, busnum 1, minor = 1
[    1.284575] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=cc60
[    1.284587] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.284598] usb 1-1: Product: AIRMAR USB<=>RS485 SerialConverter
[    1.284608] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[    1.284618] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: FTXGZX9O
[    1.285085] usb 1-1: usb_probe_device
[    1.285103] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    1.285220] usb 1-1: adding 1-1:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
[    1.290343] hub 1-0:1.0: state 7 ports 1 chg 0000 evt 0002
[    1.290390] hub 1-0:1.0: port 1 enable change, status 00000103
```

So it looks like it is connected. I have read elsewhere that `dmesg` should display a mount point. It clearly does not and I have tried all the obvious serial connections (`/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyAMA0`, `/dev/ttyAMA1`).

I can also see the device under `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0403:cc60 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
```

Not dismayed by this, I tried writing a `udev` rule in the hopes it would capture the device as it is connected and mount it for me.

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403",ATTRS{idProduct}=="cc60", ATTRS{serial}=="FTXGZX9O", SYMLINK+="airmar"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403",ATTRS{idProduct}=="cc60", ATTRS{serial}=="FTXGZX9O", MOD="0666", GROUP="ttyusb"
```

But this did not work either.

I then tried to see if I could use `udevadm info -q all` to identify more parameters for the device, but I could not find an obvious match in `tree /sys/bus/`.

I also don't know if there is anything I should do to prepare the Raspberry Pi for this type of serial connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't tried `ls /dev` with it unplugged and then `ls /dev` with it plugged in and then comparing the two outputs...?

Comment: I feel like there should be a better way to go about it, but yeah, I have. There's no difference.

Comment: Basically my question boils down to: what other steps can I take if the device shows up in `dmesg`, but isn't mounted properly?

Comment: Do you know that your device is Linux compatible? That’s a weather station multi sensor. In general when you plug a new device into a Linux computer it either is already configured for you with a driver in the default kernel or you may have to do some or a lot more work to make it compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might be custom VID/PID assigned to the device preventing the default FTDI driver module from being associated with the device correctly. As far as I know there are two ways of telling the module about the new VID/PID (other than recompiling it):

- Running `modprobe` in a `udev` rule to pass the extra parameters to the module:
  `...RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -q ftdi-sio product=0xcc60 vendor=0x0403"`
- Adding the new VID/PID to `sysfs` with a line like `echo 0403 cc60 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi-sio/new_id`. You could do this with `udev` as well or using a boot script or maybe using an entry in [`/etc/tmpfiles.d/`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#)

FTDI have a [Technical Note (TN101)](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_101_Customising_FTDI_VID_PID_In_Linux(FT_000081).pdf) about the first method but I don't think it works since the driver module was [updated](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e17c1aa2e1) to use the `sysfs` method in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the device just exposes a USB serial port. You will need to identify which serial dev node i.e. /dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttyS1 etc. The dev nodes are likely to be there all the time regardless of the device being connected.

Here is a post about how to id an active serial port dev node in Linux 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125183/how-to-find-which-serial-port-is-in-use